# Kendo line chart - switch between series

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, telerik

I am making simple line chart in kendo. Something like this demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/line-charts/index.html.

I also have mulitple series as on example(India,World etc...).

My question is, is there way to allow that only one serie is active on chart.

Series behave like checkbox button(I can have one or more active) and I want them to behave as radio button so only one serie can be active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No. You cannot modify the legend in anyway to achieve such behavior. However you can use radio buttons separately and update the options of the chart - such as the series.

Here is a small [JsBin example](http://jsbin.com/lido/2/edit):

```
  $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){

    var clickedOn = $(this).val();
    var data = $.grep(series, function(val){ 

      return val.name == clickedOn;
    })[0];

    chart.setOptions({series:[
      {
        name: clickedOn,
            data: data.data
      }
    ]})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a button.  Haven't tried it with a radio button.

```
$("#ButtonName").kendoButton({
click: function (e) {
var varname = $("#chartName").data("kendoChart")                    
kendodatasourcename.filter(
{ field: "fieldName", operator: "eq", value: "filteredvaluefromyourdataset" })
```

Comment: Please reformat your answer to use code tags for the code. Also, are you sure your answer answers the question?